# How to set the AgendaGroup in StatelessKieSession drools

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have a scenario where I want to use the `StatelessKieSession` with the agenda group. The `StatelessKieSession` doesn't have any method to set focus on a particular `AgendaGroup` like normal `KieSession` as shown below

```
KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("us").setFocus();
```

How to set a focus on a particular agendaGroup using the `StatelessKieSession`?

Answer (score 2):

You can set Agendagroup in StatelessKieSession by using **drools.setFocus()** method in your drl file. One thing you have to do explicitly is to declare a variable in your Fact object and assigned agendaGroup name to that variable. Example rule will be like :

`rule "global"
salience 100
    when
        $rec : FactObject()
    then
        drools.setFocus($rec.getAgendaValue());
end`

Give this rule a high salience value so that it gets executed first. Check [this](http://programmertech.com/program/jee/drools-tutorial-statefull-stateless-session-example) blog. They are doing the same that you are trying to do.

Comment: is there any reason behind this? I'd like to set focus from the Java code, not from the rule itself...

Comment: `Drools` don't have any method to set agenda from java in case of a `Stateless KieSession`.

Answer (score 1):

For StatelessKieSession, you can set AgendGroup and Activation Group as part of Commands

```
final List<Command> commands = newArrayList();
ClearActivationGroupCommand  activationGroup = new ClearActivationGroupCommand("Test");
commands.add(activationGroup);
AgendaGroupSetFocusCommand agendaGroup = new AgendaGroupSetFocusCommand("Test");
commands.add(agendaGroup);
final FireAllRulesCommand fireAllRulesCommand = new FireAllRulesCommand();
commands.add(fireAllRulesCommand);
final BatchExecutionCommand command = CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands);

final StatelessKieSession  session = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
ExecutionResults executionResultsSupplier =  session.execute(command);
result.setExecutionResult(executionResultsSupplier);
```

Comment: in this approach where are we setting the input request payload?